# SharePoint 2010 : Retrieve Website Properties

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am new to share point and trying this simple script to retrieve title and description of a site  it works fine when I keep siteUrl black :

```
<script language="ecmascript" type="text/ecmascript">

function GetTitleRTN(){

var siteUrl = '/ ';
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
this.oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
clientContext.load(this.oWebsite);
  ...... }
```

when I try same code with siteUrl same, it doesn't work ...

```
    <script language="ecmascript" type="text/ecmascript">     
    function GetTitleRTN() {
  var siteUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection';
  var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
  this.owebsite = clientContext.get_web().get_webs(); 
  clientContext.load(this.oWebsite);
```

....

I tried following

```
      <script language="ecmascript" type="text/ecmascript">         
       var siteUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection';
       var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
       var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
         //this.oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
        //this.owebsite = clientContext.get_web().get_webs();

   function GetTitleRTN()
      { 

   clientContext.load(oWebsite);
   ..........
    }
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

In your second example there is an error, at least here:

```
this.owebsite = clientContext.get_web().get_webs();
```

Function `SP.Web.get_webs()` returns a website collection object that represents all websites immediately beneath the website

Below is demonstrated how retrieve website with properties by its url

### How to retrieve Web Client Object properties via SharePoint CSOM (JavaScript)

```
function getWebProperties(url, OnSuccess,OnError)
{
    var context = new SP.ClientContext(url);
    var web = context.get_web();

    context.load(web);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
        function() {
          OnSuccess(web);           
        },
        OnError
    );
}


//Updated example
//Example: set value for input on button click (jQuery dependency)
$("#GetTitle").click(function() {

   getWebProperties('https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/marketing',function(web){
      $("#GetTitle").val(web.get_title());
   },
   function(sender,args){
      console.log(args.get_message());
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks !! But I ma not getting the last part of the code

Comment: <input name="GetTitle" class="ms-ButtonHeightWidth" id="GetTitle" accesskey="O" onclick="javascript:getWebProperties();" type="button" target="_self" value="Get Site Title"/><script language="ecmascript" type="text/ecmascript">

       function getWebProperties(url, OnSuccess,OnError)
      {
         var context = new SP.ClientContext(url);
         var web = context.get_web();

          context.load(web);
    ........
              },
            OnError
    );
}

         getWebProperties(..............));});</script>